# Script to find pattern in multiple lines and echo computer name that matches pattern

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a text file which contains data piped in from a PowerShell script. The data is the status of BitLocker on domain laptops. An example of what the text file contains is as follows:

```
Computer Name:        Computer1
Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted
Protection Status:    Protection On
Computer Name:        Computer2
Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted
Protection Status:    Protection Off
Computer Name:        Computer3
Conversion Status:    Fully Decrypted
Protection Status:    Protection Off
Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted
Protection Status:    Protection On
```

What I am looking for is a script which will search for all instances where two specific lines reside next to each other. So for example, in the text file, I need the script to find where the lines "Conversion Status: Fully Encrypted" and "Protection Status: Protection Off" are. Then once that requirement is met, the name of the computer which is above those two lines needs to be echoed or piped into a text file. In the example above, it would be Computer2. One thing to consider is that some systems have multiple hard drives or partitions which have separate statuses of BitLocker. So one system may have two entries in the text file like Computer3 in my example above.

The end result I would like is a text file that contains only the computer names which have the "Conversion Status: Fully Encrypted" and "Protection Status: Protection Off" as their state. I am pretty limited on my scripting skills but am capable of figuring these things out. This one has me stumped as well as the other admins I work with. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have the PowerShell script export the data as CSV instead of list format, then you can simply use `findstr`.

Comment: With a CSV I quite like using the simple [Filtering](https://www.timeatlas.com/excel-autofilter/) in Excel/Google Sheets when looking through data as you get a nice visual of your output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a text file line by line in a batch or VBS script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1065517/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart - no, the problem here is to do something depending on the content of more than one line (not doing the same thing for each of the lines in the input file).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner they haven't even shown any attempt to read a line, let's start there. The base issue is the same. The key thing here is *"I am looking for is a script"*, should ring alarm bells!

Comment: I apologize, I could have included a basic script of what I tried to use such as an If then statement but I didn't see how that would have really helped. It parsed the lines one by one and I couldn't figure out how to get it to look at more than one line at a time.

Comment: Well, if you would posted _any code_ that show your efforts, I would not downvoted your question! **`;)`**

Comment: I appreciate the welcome to the site.

Comment: @AJH You still haven't told us what you are using VBScript or Batch Script?, it can't be both and because of the lack of clarity we are getting a mixture of answers which makes this off-topic more so than it was before. I think you would benefit from reading [ask] first before posting.

Comment: @AJH well... you are coming to a site where we ask people to be clear in their question, provide their code and explain their efforts. You didn't do ANY of those things. It's not that the site isn't welcoming... it's that you stomped in here without checking what behavior you should have. We have pretty clear guidelines into asking a question.... did you go through it? Are you sure your question abides by our standards? Because if it doesn't, then yes, we will ask you to follow them, and you will get downvotes on this question in the meantime (the downvotes are on your POST, not against YOU).

Answer (score 1):

I used to not answer questions that don't show any effort from the OP; however, this problem is rather interesting!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ("!line: =!") do (
      if "%%b" equ "ComputerName" set "ConversionStatus="
      if "%%b" equ "ConversionStatus" set "ProtectionStatus="
      set "%%b=%%c"
   )
   if "!ConversionStatus!+!ProtectionStatus!" equ "FullyEncrypted+ProtectionOff" (
      echo !ComputerName!
   )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not including any code initially.

Comment: @AJH *"initially"*? As far as I can see you still haven't...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work thru a file line by line and do some action depending on the content of more than one line, you need to remember/keep state of lines seen before. To evaluate the maybe complicate boolean expression (seen this or that but not this ...), a `Select Case True/False` comes handy.

Demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oTS : Set oTS = oFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\41145072.txt")
Dim sLine, aParts, sKey, sVal, sCom, sCon, sProt
Do Until oTS.AtEndOfStream
   sLine  = oTS.ReadLine()
   aParts = Split(sLine, ":")
   If 1 = UBound(aParts) Then
        sKey   = Left(sLine, 3)
        sVal   = Trim(aParts(1))
'       WScript.Echo qq(sLine), qq(sVal)
        Select Case True
          Case sKey = "Com"
            sCom = sVal
          Case sKey = "Con"
            sCon = sVal
          Case sKey = "Pro" And sCon = "Fully Encrypted" And sVal = "Protection Off"
            WScript.Echo "****", sCom, sCon, sVal
        End Select
   Else
        WScript.Echo oTS.Line, qq(sLine), "Parse Error"
   End If
Loop
oTS.Close
```

output:

```
cscript 41145072.vbs
**** Computer2 Fully Encrypted Protection Off
```

Comment: Do you charge by the hour?

Comment: Just a variation of an [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1065589/692942).

Comment: I always find this syntax `1 = UBound(aParts)` so confusing, values are set  with the variable on the left and the assignment on the right. Why switch that around on a comparison?, just really grates on me - *sorry*.

Answer (score 0):

A powershell solution with two RegExes.
The first splits the file into chunks starting with `Computer Name`

The second one uses a named capture group to grep the computer name and checks the condition.

```
$InFile = ".\41145072.txt"

$Delimiter = 'Computer Name:'
$Escaped   = [regex]::Escape($Delimiter)
$Split     = "(?!^)(?=$Escaped)"
$Search = [RegEx]'(?smi)Computer Name:\s+(?<ComputerName>[0-9a-z_-]+).*Fully Encrypted\r\nProtection Status:\s+Protection Off'

(Get-Content $InFile -Raw) -split $Split | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_ -match $Search){
      $matches.ComputerName
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is Powershell mentioned?, it's already tagged VBScript and Batch-File doesn't need a third.

Comment: @Lankymart Having a bad mood today? Well the first sentence mentions powershell as the origin of the file. Of course it would be better first place piping to another Powershell script/cmdlet to do the filtering. I don't feel my script out of order. BTW wasn't it you who once wrongly accused me of not providing a solution?

Comment: Not at all just sick of people ignoring the guidelines / flouting them when it suits. Your answer is fine the problem lies with the question, so by process of elimination the answer shouldn't exist but it does. I wrongly accused you of something, you got a source for that?...I honestly don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "namefound="
SET "convstatfullenc="
SET "protstatoff="

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q41141572.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2*delims=: " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "lineprocessed="
 IF /i "%%a"=="computer" IF /i "%%b"=="name" (
  SET "namefound=%%c"
  SET "convstatfullenc="
  SET "protstatoff="
  SET "lineprocessed=Y"
 )
 IF /i "%%a"=="protection" (
  SET "protstatoff="
  IF /i "%%b"=="status" IF /i "%%c"=="protection off" (
   SET "protstatoff=Y"
   SET "lineprocessed=Y"
  )
 )
 IF /i "%%a"=="conversion" (
  SET "convstatfullenc="
  SET "protstatoff="
  IF /i "%%b"=="status" IF /i "%%c"=="fully encrypted" (
   SET "convstatfullenc=Y"
   SET "lineprocessed=Y"
  )
 )
 IF DEFINED lineprocessed IF DEFINED namefound IF DEFINED convstatfullenc IF DEFINED protstatoff (
  CALL ECHO %%namefound%%
  SET "lineprocessed="
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED lineprocessed (
  SET "convstatfullenc="
  SET "protstatoff="
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q41141572.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Working  on the first word only, if the words are `computer` and `name` then a new `namefound` is assigned and the two flags `convstatfullenc` and `protstatoff` are cleared and the line marked read. Consequently, the control flags are cleared whenever a new `computer name` is encountered.

If `conversion` is encountered, then the control flags are cleared and `convstatfullenc` is only set if the line contains `status` and `fully encrypted` when the line is marked as processed.

if `protection` is encountered, then `protstatoff` will only be set if the line also contains `status` and `protection off` when the line will again be marked processed.

If the line has been processed and each flag is set, then each condition has been met so show the name stored. clearing `lineprocessed`  ensures that the two control flags are cleared at the next step.

So, if a line that is none of the three target lines is found, the line is not set to processed, so the two control flags are cleared.

If the `conversion` line is found, `protstatoff` is cleared and `convstatfullenc` *may* be set.

if the `protection` line is found, `protstatoff` *may* be set.

The only way in which **both** control flags may be set is for the `protection` line to be directly after the `conversion` line **and** both to pass the full test.

Comment: You honestly think that a question with no clear problem, no [mcve] and ambiguity of what they are actually using *(I see you chose to go with Batch-File)* should be encouraged by answering them?

Comment: @Lankymart: No. And Yes. After 15 years' unemployment, I need something to keep my mind active. There aren't enough problems being posted to insist that "the rules" be adhered to, so I answer what amuses me. Sure - if someone wants me to do the job they can't do, then either they will learn something, so my effort isn't wasted, or they will mindlessly parrot what I've posted without understanding it. If this causes a problem for their employer at some time in the future, then it suits my purpose since the employer's choice of employees comes back to bite them.see it as a little Machiavellian.

Comment: You can amuse yourself by flagging questions, voting, editing and reviewing...you don't need to contribute to the already hefty problem.

Comment: Maybe the problem is you need to move away from batch to something more mainstream *(just judging from your profile)*. I can't imagine there is much call for Batch programmers now.

Comment: @Lankymart: I prefer the culture in the batch-file tag. Participants co-operate to build solutions whereas in "more mainstream" areas, high-rep contributors & their followers form destructive cliques which serially vote-down any suggestion from a non-member of that clique for such crimes as posting in-line comments instead of a separate commentary or attempting to solve a problem posted by someone who is having difficulty framing their problem in English. It amuses me to use an ancient underpowered language to solve problems, same as using a manual 1890s coffee-grinder instead of packaged mud.

Comment: Seems you have a bit of a chip on your shoulder. Not surprised you get a hostile reception if you do things like you have done here, in which case I'll leave you to it.